# Paperclip: How to get image URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to switch my Rails server to AngularJS. Everything worked fine so far, but I don't know how to get the image url from Paperclip.

The current data I'm receiving is:

```
{
  "id":52, 
  "name":"Samsung-Galaxy", 
  "cost":500, "brand":"Samsung", 
  "description":" Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text when ...", 
  "created_at":"2015-06-02T09:43:10.000Z", 
  "updated_at":"201509:43:10.000Z", 
  "avatar_file_name":"382727-samsung-galaxy-s-4-t-mobile.jpg", 
  "avatar_content_type":"image/jpeg", "avatar_file_size":20829, 
  "avatar_updated_at":"201502T09:43:10.000Z"
}
```

But how to display image on html page.

Comment: Show us the file where you generate the json

Comment: in my angular controller using the statement like  $scope.product = Product.get({id: $routeParams.id})

Comment: and the API response from the server that sends the object?

Comment: yes but how to get actual file path..?

Comment: @Sathibabu-Nyros. do you have 382727-samsung-galaxy-s-4-t-mobile.jpg this image in your any folder?

Comment: @Angu - Yes it has in Store/public/system/products/avatars/000/000/052/thumb/382727-samsung-galaxy-s-4-t-mobile.jpg

Answer (score 1):

When you have Paperclip set up in your model like so:

```
class Phone
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

You can easily get the different images from your `Phone object`, [as described in the docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view).

```
@medium_avatar_url = Phone.first.avatar.url(:medium)
```

Of course you wouldn't send it via an instance variable, but rather implement it into your JSON response.

The quick fix would be:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@product[:avatar_url] = @product.avatar.url(:medium)
respond_with(@product.as_json)
```

But I *highly* recommend you check out [the  jbuilder gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), this will give you a lot more flexibility. 
There's also a [great Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder) to get you going!

Comment: you surely have a controller that sends variables to your JSON response. Or how do you generate your JSON?

Comment: @product = Product.find(params[:id])
 respond_with(@product.as_json)

Comment: I updated my answer, you should definitely check out the recommended gem

Answer (score -2):

Add one more **url** filed to JSON data to put image actual path on generate rails controller like this ...

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@product[:url] = @product.avatar.url(:medium) //paperclip method
respond_with(@product.as_json)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I said..., rather than posting it again as your own answer accept the answer that worked for you.

Comment: I updated my answer to include your quickfix, I still *highly* recommend you check out jbuilder.